# firefox addon Stylish gives me random error message

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm running on `Ubuntu 12.04`. I installed `Stylish` addon today.
I write a new style:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("weibo.com") {

    #pl_content_pullylist {
        display:   none;    
    }

}
```

When I press <kbd>Preview</kbd> button, it print:

```
6:23 Error in parsing value for 'display'. Declaration dropped.
```

When I remove the space before `none`, it works again. I cannot put `>2` spaces there.
Sometimes, I need to remove all spaces and indentations to make it work.
Sometimes, It doesn't work no matter what I do.
It behaves random.

Comment: I see no errors in the CSS. Are you using `Stylish 1.2.6`? Which version of Firefox? I'll see if I can replicate this on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. :(

Comment: This warning doesn't come from Stylish but rather from the browser itself - and it shouldn't depend on spaces unless you have some very unusual kind of spaces there (there are all kinds of invisible characters in Unicode).

Comment: It's normal `space` char. Because, I type them one by one. And `stylish` print error message, when I typed 3 spaces.